# Simultaneously copying and renaming directory in ant

Tags: java, html, ant

I've looked through ant tasks like copy, but can't really seem to find a way. With this kind of file structure:

```
/Resources/Docs/SpecificDoc/ScalaDocs
```

I want to rename "ScalaDocs" to "TargetDocs", having an end structure like so:

```
/Resources/Docs/TargetDocs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
<copy todir="/Resources/Docs/TargetDocs">
    <fileset dir="/Resources/Docs/SpecificDoc/ScalaDocs">
        <include name="*" />
    </fileset>
</copy>
```